# How to change histogram color based on x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have this histogram computed from a pandas dataframe.

[image]

I want to change the colors based on the x-axis values.
For example:

```
If the value is = 0 the color should be green
If the value is > 0 the color should be red
If the value is < 0 the color should be yellow
```

I'm only concerned with the x-axis.  The height of the bar doesn't matter much to me.  All other solutions are for the y-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each bar patch in `ax.containers[0]`, use [`set_color`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_color) based on the `x` position:

- [`get_x`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.get_x) returns the left edge, so get the midpoint by adding half of [`get_width`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.get_width)
- `x` probably won't be *exactly* 0, so test with some buffer (0.2 in this example)

Since you [asked for pandas in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70202374/how-to-change-histogram-color-based-on-x-axis-in-matplotlib#comment124102024_70202516), this example uses [`DataFrame.plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html), but you can do this with any matplotlib-based histogram/bar plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.default_rng(222).uniform(-1, 1, 40)})
ax = df.plot.hist()

for bar in ax.containers[0]:
    # get x midpoint of bar
    x = bar.get_x() + 0.5 * bar.get_width()

    # set bar color based on x
    if x < -0.2:
        bar.set_color('orange')
    elif x > 0.2:
        bar.set_color('red')
    else:
        bar.set_color('green')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just plot them one by one:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1,10)
width = 0.2
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
cmap = mpl.cm.RdYlGn.reversed()
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)
for x0, y0 in zip(x,y):
    plt.bar(x0, y0, width = width, color = cmap(norm(np.abs(x0*10))))
```

[image]

Comment: I want to change the colors based on the value on the x axis.

Comment: @roger this is changed based on x axis `color = cmap(norm(np.abs(x0*10)))`

Comment: @Z li Could you explain what's happening in the code? When I plug my data in the whole thing turns green? Like a green square.

Comment: the color is determined by a color map `cmap ` and it is normalized to a range of `[0, 10]`. In the color part I set the color accordingly given by `x0`. Since the value of `x0` here is small (-1 to 1) I multiply it by 10. If you getting all green it is probably because your x values are too small (small value gets green and larger ones get red)

Comment: Also if you are getting a huge square it is probably because you set the `width` of the bars to be too large

Comment: I've played with it for a while.  What would be the best way to add a pandas df to your solution?  Your solution works as is but I can't get it to work with my solution.  Sometimes it's all green, sometimes it's all yellow.  I changed the x variable to be my actual data and I changed the y to be just a count to 20 because it really doesn't matter to me.  But that didn't give me similar results to what you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239787/discussion-between-roger-and-z-li).